# How to compare two dimensional string array with string variable?

Tags: java, arrays

This code doesn't work. Whats wrong in it?

```
String arr[][] ={{"Jerry","s"},{"Jerry1","s1"},{"Oya","e"}};

    String app1 = "Oya";

    for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++){
            if(app1.equals(arr[i][i])){
                    appstr = arr[i][i+1];
                    return appstr;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger. The problem will show.

Comment: While debugging It is crashing at 3rd loop

Comment: Fix this if(app1.equals(arr[i][i])) arr[2][2] will be invalid and so will arr[i][i+1]

Comment: Sure enough. While debugging, watch closely what cell of your array you're accessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your secondary array subscripts are wrong. You know that the second dimension of the array will only ever be `0` - the word to compare and `1` - the value to return.  This will do what you want:

```
String arr[][] = {
    {"Jerry",  "s" },
    {"Jerry1", "s1"},
    {"Oya",    "e" }
};

String app1 = "Oya";

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (app1.equals(arr[i][0])) {
        return arr[i][1];
    }
}
```